Redis doesn't allow SSH connections when installed in the User-data of a AWS EC2 Instance
Basically in my User-data script, I'm simply trying to install redis-server to launch my own NodeJs application. But everytime that I install it, I can't connect to the Instance, through console or cli. I tried a lot of things, the SSH 22 port is open to anyone, the TCP 6379 is also open, and if I don't install redis, the script runs fine. This is my script:
#cloud-boothook
#!/bin/bash

# Update package lists
sudo apt update

# Install Redis
sudo apt install -y redis-server

# Allow connections from remote hosts
sudo sed -i "s/bind 127.0.0.1/bind 0.0.0.0/g" /etc/redis/redis.conf

# Disable protected mode
sudo sed -i "s/protected-mode yes/protected-mode no/g" /etc/redis/redis.conf

# Restart Redis to apply changes
sudo systemctl restart redis-server

# Check iptables rules for port 6379
sudo iptables -L INPUT -n --line-numbers | grep 6379

# Remove any iptables rules blocking traffic on port 6379
sudo iptables -D INPUT <rule_number>

# Save iptables configuration
sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4


This line isn't saving the list of rules or anything, it's just printing them to the console: sudo iptables -L INPUT -n --line-numbers | grep 6379 Then this line seems to have a rule_number placeholder that you aren't actually populating as far as I can tell sudo iptables -D INPUT <rule_number>, so I think it is actually deleting all inbound rules.

Note that userdata scripts run as root so no need for sudo (unless you want certain commands run as a non-root user).
